# Enabling Ahead of time compilation for Xamarin project

Tags: performance, xamarin, optimization, compilation, aot

I have a xamarin application which is very slow, I need to improve this performance, with a little research I came across this concept of Ahead of time compilation. But I am not sure how to enable it for my project.

`<AotAssemblies>True</AotAssemblies>`

Apparently, I need to set this property to true in my .csproj file But I can't seem to find the file. Any help would be appreciated
Plus this is my first question on StackOverflow so I hope to find some help.

Comment: Hi, more information about [AOT](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/aot/#aoting-all-the-system-libraries), you could refer to this. And what do you mean *I have a xamarin application which is very slow*?  If build solw, you could set [Link Beavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#linker-behavior) to improve it.

Comment: Application is slow, it takes alot of time to load

Comment: Okey, whether the project use the latest version of nuget packages?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much all the stable versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property need to be setted in native **.csproj**, but there is a easy way to set that with GUI of Visual stuido.

For example, if want to set for **Android** in **Visual Studio for PC**, packaging properties can be set in the **Android Options** section of project **Properties**, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

and then you will see it in **.csproj** of Android solution.(Unload Android Solution will see this file):

[image]

In **iOS**, you will not need to set **AOT**, because iOS will use **[AOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/architecture#aot)** as default.

> However, there is a security restriction on iOS, set by Apple, which disallows the execution of dynamically generated code on a device. To ensure that we adhere to these safety protocols, Xamarin.iOS instead uses an Ahead of Time (AOT) compiler to compile the managed code.